# How to start a movie clip at a certain frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This should be very simple, but I cannot find a solution.
I have a movie clip, a circle which changes color.
On the main timeline, this circle moves from left side to right side.
My problem is, that I want the circle to start to change color is the middle.
I want to start its loop in frame_x.
How do I stop it in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The methods that you might find helpful for this are:

[`stop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#stop%28%29)
[`play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#play%28%29)
[`gotoAndStop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29)
[`gotoAndPlay()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29)